# Routing in cake php

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, routes

i am having following url

```
example.com/show.php?xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I want to redirect it to the controller tests action redirs.
How can i achieve this with cake php routing or via htaccess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just enter a plain route for this in the `app/Config/routes.php` file:

```
Router::connect('/show.php', array('controller' => 'tests', 'action' => 'redirs'));
```

Within your action you can process whatever is passed in the querystring, if there is a need for that.